# getting wrong label encoding for user input in Skikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have encoded my labels by using this code for train data in python 3:

[image]

After training my model I want to test it by using the input from the user when I convert user input to label encoding then it encode the user input wrong, as Short(hair) have label of 3 in the previous set but in user input all label will be assigned to 0. what is my logical error?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guideline before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do label encoding for traind and test set, you are not allowed to re-train your label encoder.

You have to use in training part: `fit_transform`
and in test part only: `transform`

Youa re using to different encoders right now, which is the wrong approach.